# Query JPA usando Paginação está demorando mais conforme o número da pagina aumenta, e gerando timeout

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa, spring-boot

Estou rodando uma query com `JPA` em um servidor de cloud do google app engine, essa query deveria me trazer milhões de registros, e por isso estou usando Pageable nela, para evitar timeout do banco, o problema é que conforme o número da página aumenta mais tempo ela demora pra carregar os registros, descobri isso através de logs que coloquei. por exemplo a página `0` traz `1000` registros em `0,18` segundos, já a pagina `942` que é a última antes de dar erro trás os `1000` registros só depois de `174` segundos e depois da erro 404 no server. Esta a query que eu estou rodando:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT c.idCliente, tel.idTelefone, tel.numeroSemMascara "  
        + "FROM Cliente AS c LEFT JOIN ("  
            + "SELECT cfa.idCliente, cfa.tempoDuracaoBotija, max(cfa.dataCadastro) AS ultimoCadastro " 
            + "FROM ClienteFogasAvisa AS cfa GROUP BY cfa.idCliente, cfa.tempoDuracaoBotija " 
            + ") AS fa "
        + "ON c.idCliente = fa.idCliente "  
        + "INNER JOIN Telefone as tel "  
        + "ON c.idCliente = tel.idCliente "  
        + "INNER JOIN Endereco as e "  
        + "ON c.idCliente = e.idCliente "  
        + "WHERE c.idCliente NOT IN ("
            + "SELECT ec.idCliente FROM EnvioCampanha AS ec "
            + "WHERE c.idCliente = ec.idCliente "
            + "AND ec.idMensagem = 'NFS10' "
            + "AND ec.situacao = 'Enviado' "
            + "AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), ec.dataEnvio) < 365) "   
        + "AND c.situacao = 'Ativo' " 
        + "AND tel.situacao = 'Ativo' AND tel.tipoTelefone = 'Celular' AND (tel.envioSMS IS NULL OR tel.envioSMS = 1) " 
        + "AND tel.numeroSemMascara IS NOT NULL " 
        + "AND (COALESCE(:idClientes) IS NULL OR (c.idCliente in (:idClientes))) " 
        + "AND (COALESCE(:siglaEstados) IS NULL OR (e.siglaEstado in (:siglaEstados))) "
        + "AND (COALESCE(:cidades) IS NULL OR (e.cidade in (:cidades))) " 
        + "AND e.situacao = 'Ativo' " 
        + "AND (fa.idCliente is null " 
        + "OR ((fa.tempoDuracaoBotija is null or fa.tempoDuracaoBotija = 0) and DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), fa.ultimoCadastro) >= 365) " 
        + "OR (DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), fa.ultimoCadastro) >= 1095))", nativeQuery = true)
public List<Object[]> getClientesMuitoTempoSemResponderFogasAvisa(@Param("idClientes") List<Integer> idClientes,
        @Param("siglaEstados") List<String> siglaEstados, @Param("cidades") List<String> cidades, Pageable page);
```

Este é o método que está usando a query:

```
@Override
public List<ClienteCampanhaDTO> getClientes(List<Integer> idClientes, List<String> siglaEstados,
        List<String> cidades, Campanha camp) {
    int pagina = 0;
    List<ClienteCampanhaDTO> clientes = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Object[]> clientesTuple = new ArrayList<>();

    tracer.info("iniciou a busca dos clientes da NFS 10");

    /**
     * se a nfs 10 para de dar erro 404 apagar esses logs de calculo de tempo depois disso
     */
    do {
        Long inicioBuscaBanco = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
        clientesTuple = clienteRepository.getClientesMuitoTempoSemResponderFogasAvisa(idClientes, siglaEstados,
                cidades, PageRequest.of(pagina, MIL));
        Long fimBuscaBanco = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
        Long inicioMontagemCliente = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
        criarClientes(clientesTuple, clientes);
        Long fimMontagemCliente = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();

        Long duracaoBuscaBanco = fimBuscaBanco - inicioBuscaBanco;
        Long duracaoMontagemCliente = fimMontagemCliente - inicioMontagemCliente;

        Float duracaoBuscaBancoEmSegundos = duracaoBuscaBanco / 1000f;
        Float duracaoMontagemClienteEmSegundos = duracaoMontagemCliente / 1000f;

        tracer.info("Demorou " + String.format("%.2f", duracaoBuscaBancoEmSegundos) + " para buscar os clientes da pagina " + pagina);
        tracer.info("Demorou " + String.format("%.2f", duracaoMontagemClienteEmSegundos) + " para instanciar os clientes da pagina " + pagina);

        pagina++;
    } while (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(clientesTuple));

    tracer.info("finalizou a busca dos clientes da NFS 10");

    return clientes;
}
```

E este é o método que pega a tupla retornada e cria um cliente(não há problema algum aqui, coloquei ele só para não deixar o código incompleto)

```
/**
 * Pega a tupla de colunas buscadas do banco de dados e instancia um objeto do
 * tipo cliente e depois o adiciona a lista final de clientes
 * 
 * @param clientesTuple - lista com todas a colunas buscadas no banco de dados
 * @param clientes      - lista final de clientes que receberão a mensagem
 */
private void criarClientes(List<Object[]> clientesTuple, List<ClienteCampanhaDTO> clientes) {
    for (Object[] cliente : clientesTuple) {
        try {
            ClienteCampanhaDTO clienteEncontrado = new ClienteCampanhaDTO();
            clienteEncontrado.setIdCliente((Integer) cliente[ID_CLIENTE]);
            clienteEncontrado.setIdTelefone((Integer) cliente[ID_TELEFONE]);
            clienteEncontrado.setTelefoneCliente((String) cliente[NUMERO_SEM_MASCARA]);
            clientes.add(clienteEncontrado);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            tracer.error("Houve um erro ao instanciar um cliente na NFS10");
        }
    }
}
```

Como faço para que o número de páginas não influencie na velocidade da pesquisa?

Comment: Qual banco de dados está utilizando? Dependendo da especificação do banco de dados, por mais que você esteja utilizando paginação, ele vai realizar a query com todos os resultados e só depois calcular qual página deve retornar, o que vai gerando lentidão ao caminhar nas páginas

Comment: Estou usando o mysql, pois é a implementação padrão que o cliente SQL do Google Cloud oferece. Será que é esse o problema?

Comment: Provavelmente, o MySQL funciona dessa maneira, você pode rodar um `EXPLAIN` em sua query e verificar isso quando estiver fazendo um fetch de uma página muito adiante do índice 0

Comment: Existem uns materiais bem interessantes para você verificar como [este](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481388/why-does-mysql-higher-limit-offset-slow-the-query-down) e [este](https://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/)

Comment: Uma boa estratégia seria sempre considerar o índices através de IDs, como apontado em um desses links.